# How can I make this code loop? [discord.js]

Tags: javascript, loops, discord.js

I'm trying to get this to successfully loop in my Discord bot. What I want is when the command runs, the bot picks a song from `1-10` and plays it (already done), *and* after that song is played it should repeat picking a song and playing it.

I'm not sure how to do this.

This is my code:

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    var isReady = true;

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (message.content === `${prefix}KOLARADIO`) {
        if (message.member.voice.channel) {
            const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();

            songRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

            if (songRandom === 1) {
                const dispatcher = connection.play('KOCK_MUSIC/a.mp3')
                dispatcher.on('start', () => {
                    console.log('audio ' + songRandom + ' is playing');
                });

                dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
                    console.log('audio has finished playing');
                })

                dispatcher.on('error', console.error);
            }

            else if (songRandom === 2) {
                const dispatcher = connection.play('KOCK_MUSIC/b.mp3')
                dispatcher.on('start', () => {
                    console.log('audio ' + songRandom + ' is playing');
                });

                dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
                    console.log('audio has finished playing');
                });

                dispatcher.on('error', console.error);
            }

            else if ...
            }
            return songRandom;
        };
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a couple suggestions, the last of which will allow you to play your playlist forever, but requires both of the preceding ones to work.

First, you need to put your songs in an array. That way you don't need to repeat yourself to play different songs.

```js
const songs = [
   'KOCK_MUSIC/a.mp3',
    // ... more music
];
```

Second your song picker should use songs.length to pick the next song, instead of relying on you having 10 songs. This way you can add and remove songs later without your code breaking.

Finally, you should have a function like this.

```js
playSong() {
    const songId = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length);
    connection.play(songs[songId]).on("finish", playSong);
}
```

This will recursively play a new song when the previous song finishes. Be careful, this should run forever. You may want to give it a way to stop.